# Solve the following matrix equation $X'X=A$

Tags: matrices, regularization

I have square matrices $X$,$A$ and $X'X-A=0$. $A$ is given and is positive definite and I need to get matrix $X$. 
I know $X$ is not unique since $TX$ such that $T'T=I$ will satisfy.
My problem is that is it possible to combine the equation with some prior knowledge (some sort of restriction) such as symmetry, triangularity, sparsity and somehow get a **unique** $X$.

Many thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition

Answer (score 1):

A positive definite matrix $A$ has a unique positive definite square root.
If we diagonalize $A$ as $A = U D U^*$ with $U$ a unitary matrix and $D$ diagonal, then 
this square root is $X = U \sqrt{D} U^*$ where $\sqrt{D}$ is the diagonal matrix whose elements are the square roots of the corresponding elements of $D$.
If $A$ is real, $U$ is orthogonal and $X$ is real and symmetric.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I guess my point is that the unitary matrix $U$ is not unique so different choices of unitary matrices would lead to different $X$ and I want to find out if we could impose some restriction that gives unique $U$